# jQuery .css does not work for all IDs in list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to dynamically set the css style of some divs which are listed. When I iterate over them, and set their new css values, only the last div will get the new css values.

```
for (var i = 0, l = list.length; i < l; i++)
{
  b = list[i];

  b.$block.css({
    "top": b.pos.y + "px",
    "left": b.pos.x + "px"
  });

  b.pos = b.pos.add(b.vec);
}
```

b.$block is the jQuery object. b.pos and b.vec are just some Vector2D instances which I use to calculate the top and left value all divs.

Comment: It should work as expected. You can use `$.each` to iterate over your list. Consider also to debug your code and see if `b.$block` is really a jQuery object. If it's just an element you can wrap it inside `$(element)` to make jQuery collection from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### New solution

You forgot 3 times the keyword `new`:

```
return (Vector2D(that.x + other.x, that.y + other.y)); // line 92

return (Vector2D(that.x - other.x, that.y - other.y)); // line 96

metaList.push(createBlock(i)); // line 133
```

You have to write

```
return (new Vector2D(that.x + other.x, that.y + other.y)); // line 92

return (new Vector2D(that.x - other.x, that.y - other.y)); // line 96

metaList.push(new createBlock(i)); // line 133
```

Just with the `new` keyword the `this` parameter of the functions is set to a new value. Here the code: http://jsfiddle.net/6eB3U/1/

### Old solution

Here you have a debugged example of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/8ET77/

Consider the function `createBlock()`:

```
function createBlock(idx)
{
    var tmp = new Array(4);

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if (i < 2)
            tmp[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) % 600; 
        else
            tmp[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) % 4;
    }

    this.pos = new Vector2D(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
    this.vec = new Vector2D(tmp[2], tmp[3]);
    this.$block = $("#block"+idx);

    return this;
}
```

For each call on the function, the reference `this` points to the same object (i.e. the function object `createBlock()`). The corrected function now looks like this:

```
function createBlock(idx)
{
    var tmp = new Array(4);

    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         if (i < 2)
             tmp[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 1000) % 600; 
         else
             tmp[i] = Math.round(Math.random() * 10) % 4;
    }

    block = {}; // new object is generated here!

    block.pos = new Vector2D(tmp[0], tmp[1]);
    block.vec = new Vector2D(tmp[2], tmp[3]);
    block.$block = $("#block"+idx);

    return block;
}
```

You have to make the same correction for the function `Vector2D()`.

Comment: Thanks, I had to apply the solution that you suggested to the Vector2D function too. I think I am too Python-orientated.

Comment: @maikovich : You are right: http://jsfiddle.net/6eB3U/ I will update my answer...

Answer (score 4):

The css() method does affect all the jQuery objects in the collection, but if you run your code in a debugger, you can see that you are passing the same object every time: div#block3.

Your problem lies elsewhere outside of the blockSim(list) method because you are passing a list of the same object.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I found the flaw.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to use jQuery [$.each](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function? It is probably solve your problem.

It just may something like that.

```
$.each(b.$block, function( index, value ) {
  $(value).css({"top" , b.pos.x + "px"});
});
```